# Can I use something other than AES 128 to store my PSCredential?

Tags: password-management, aes, powershell, windows-7

From what I've [read](http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/) the ConvertTo-SecureString will store a password with AES-128 (which as I understand it is cracked)...is it possible to use more bits?

I've read in `Get-Help` the following, but I don't know how to proceed:

```
If an encryption key is specified by using the Key or SecureKey
parameters, the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) encryption algorithm is
used. The specified key must have a length of 128, 192, or 256 bits
because those are the key lengths supported by the AES encryption
algorithm. If no key is specified, the Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI)
is used to encrypt the standard string representation.
```

Also, I'd like to run it with a Scheduled Task in Windows.

Comment: AES-128 is very much **not** cracked. I don't know where you read this, but it is not true at all.

Comment: @Polynomial http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/08/06/researchers_crack_sim_card_aes128_encryption_in_10_minutes_for_cloning/

Comment: That is a side-channel attack against the processor; it says so quite clearly in the article. Nobody cracked AES, they identified weaknesses in the implementation of the algorithm in the SIM, allowing them to extract the key material by very carefully monitoring the power consumption of the device. As the article states, side-channel attacks go *around* the encryption, they don't crack it.

Comment: The article actually links to [a Sec.SE answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61346/how-long-would-it-take-to-bruteforce-an-aes-128-protected-pdf-knowing-the-key-is/61357#61357) which explains exactly how long it'd take to crack AES-128: forever, essentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use *up to* AES 256 as mentioned [here](http://www.quickstart.com/knowledge-center/quickstart-blog/2015/05/13/powershell-credentials-and-securestrings-part-iii).

> **ConvertFrom-SecureString** and **ConvertTo-SecureString** have two
>   parameters that you can use to change the default behavior.  These
>   parameters are –SecureKey and –Key.  The –SecureKey parameter takes a
>   SecureString object and the –Key parameter, a byte array (Byte[])
>
> You use **–SecureKey** with a SecureString memory object that encrypt and
>   decrypt the other SecureString.  This does not really help us in our
>   goal of storing secure passwords and accessing them through
>   automation.  You would need a SecureString object built, either by
>   unencrypting another string using another option, or by having someone
>   type the SecureString interactively.   The first does not solve the
>   problem of it being secured, the second does not solve the automation
>   problem.
>
> The **–Ke**y parameter allows you to use a 128-bit (16-byte), 192-bit
>   (24-byte), or 256-bit (32-byte) key and uses the Advanced Encryption
>   System (AES) cipher, also known as the Rijndael cipher, to
>   encrypt/decrypt the SecureString.  It is symmetric encryption so you
>   need to provide the same key for encryption as you do when you decrypt
>   the encrypted string back to the SecureString.  One way to do this is
>   to embed the key in each script file.  Not surprising, this not
>   recommended and results in security not much more secure than just
>   storing the password in plain text in the script.  It also makes it
>   difficult to change the key or password which should due frequently
>   using this method.  A better choice is to store the key in a separate
>   file from the script and encrypted password.

Comment: I hate to ask, but what are all those numbers in $Key?

Comment: That's the **key** represented as an array of bytes (hence why none of those numbers exceeds 255). In this case there are 32 bytes -indicating a 256 bit encryption key.

Comment: Okay couldn't see that from the picture or the docs; thanks for letting me know!

Comment: You should be able to copy and paste from this example, but it goes without saying you should come up with new numbers for each of the 32 bits, just don't exceed the number "255" for any given position.